# UITextField with secureTextEntry enable and right alignment

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have an issue with my textfield and the way it displays its value when I enable the property `secureTextEntry` and set the alignment to the right.

The standard behavior, when `secureTextEntry` is enable, is to display dots instead of character except for the last one which is visible. It works fine until the width of the value become higher than the width of the textfield: in this case, the last character is truncated as you can see here (`UITextfield`'s background color is in red and last character must be a "z"):

[image]

[image]

I'm working with XCode 7 and iOS 9. Size or constraint on the textfield doesn't change anything. I'm stuck :(

To reproduce this behavior, create an `UIViewController` and simply add this code in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 20)];
tf.secureTextEntry = YES;
tf.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
tf.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
[self.view addSubview:tf];
```

Comment: I can see "Z" as the last character. What do you mean by truncated ?

Comment: My example is maybe not the best but the fact is the right part of the last character is missing.

Comment: You mean the "Z" is not fully visible. Right ? It is because the blue pointer (cursor) is taking place the other half part.

Comment: You mean the "Z" is not fully visible -> Yes. But even without the blue cursor, "z" is not fully visible, I updated my answer with a new screenshot

Comment: That's weird. Make sure no other view is overlapping on the textField.

Comment: I tried to put just an UITextfield on my viewController and the result is the same. I added some code in my question to reproduce this behavior.